# Set domain of session cookie dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, subdomain

I use session objects in my web application which are traced by ASP.NET session cookie internally as we all know. So access to that cookie is essential to have access to session objects. I want my asp.net application work under `http://` and `http://www` or any subdomain (domain is unknown to me at development time).

Comment: Do you mean how to share the cookies in sub domain.. or when they are used with or without "www"....???

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. The session cookie only works for 1 domain and 1 domain only.

You could, however, write your own session management system and maybe accomplish shared session that way. I still don't think you'd be able re-use the cookie because the browser won't even send it in the first place.

---

After some more thought I've decided that I'm not sure. :) Perhaps if both subdomains map to the same ASP.NET application you could get share session to work. All you'd have to do is set your cookies as such:

```
  <httpCookies domain=".maindomain.com">
```

If the different subdomians don't map to the same app, I think you'd definitely have to write your own session management.

---

Clearly, at this point you should take everything I've written with a grain of salt. I'm only leaving my answer up for you to get some ideas and so that people may comment on the correctness of it.

Comment: It's possible. The domain is not gonna change in the application life cycle. It's known some day. You can get current domain via `Request.Url` and set `ASP.NET_SessionId` at run-time but it's a little tricky and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Now we are closer. In fact I do the same as your suggestion (usnig `httpCookies` in webconfig) for now but looking for some code to put behind aspx pages where the session is manipulated. Then I can remove that web.config hard-coded key and application works on any domain. What I need is to do what this key does in code (where at run-time I know the domain).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you leave domain field empty? That way you won't bind your cookies to some specific domain and will be able to play well whatever the domain of your site will be.

Comment: No. Leaving it empty means it will use *exactly* the domain that the request came from. So, if you're on www.site.com, the cookie will be set for www.site.com and NOT be available to *.site.com.